# How do I get only one result for each app instead of double?

Tags: vb.net, windows-firewall

Copy this into Visual Studio, add a textbox and it'll run.

```
Const NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW = 1
Dim fwPolicy2 = CreateObject("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2")
Dim RulesObject = fwPolicy2.Rules

For Each rule In RulesObject
    If rule.action = NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW Then
        TextBox1.Text += rule.name & vbnewline
    End If
Next
```

This is an example of what I get but I only need each app to be listed once, not two times. What am I doing wrong or why does it behave like this?

```
qBittorrent
qBittorrent
Chrome
Chrome
Visual Studio
Visual Studio
and so on...
```

Comment: Why do you use both + and & for your strings? For strings use only &. You can use AppendText too when adding stuff to textbox.

Comment: Oh you mean like this. `TextBox1.AppendText(rule.name & vbNewLine)` Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Another small tip: instead of the "old school" `vbNewLine`, you can use `Environment.NewLine`, which I always personally prefer, as it keeps things object oriented. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It behaves like this because `rule.Name` is not a unique identifier for a firewall rule. The same rule name may be used for different protocols (TCP, UDP), profiles (domain, private, public), direction (in, out), etc. If you are only interested in `rule.Name`, add them to a set, then print that set, as follows.

```
Const NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW = 1
Dim fwPolicy2 = CreateObject("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2")
Dim RulesObject = fwPolicy2.Rules
Dim names As New HashSet(Of String)

' Create set of unique names.
For Each rule In fwPolicy2.Rules
    If rule.action = NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW Then
        names.Add(rule.name)
    End If
Next

' Add names to TextBox.
For Each name As String In names
    TextBox1.Text += name & vbNewLine
Next
```

Comment: I tested this code. It does give only one app name as I wanted but what I don't get is why. It's not too different from my code except for the `hashset`so what in this code does that, and how?

Comment: Okay, just googled it up: "The Hashset class store non-duplicate items". Nice.

Comment: @user11903887 - And adding an element to a hashset takes contant time, that is, it is not necessary to scan all elements already in the set to determine whether an element already exists. This is why I suggested using a set, for its performance. Searching whether a name already exists in your TextBox.Text takes time proportional to the length of Text, and that length increases as each name is appended to it. So, a search time that is not constant but proportional to the length of Text.

Comment: @user11903887 Please accept Robert's answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Comment: @Mary - I like the other response as well. The `hashset`version from Robert is good but as he suggests himself, it could be a slow and resource heavy solution while Scott's seems to me as easier on the resources and possibly faster. So which of the two responses is the most effective? Let me test some more and get back with a desicion.

Comment: @ user11903887 - You misunderstood my comment. It is the opposite, Scott's answer has a quadratic time complexity, while mine is linear. Linear is faster than quadratic. Linear means that if there are n rules, the execution time is proportional to n. Quandratic means it is proportional to n^2 (n x n).

Comment: @RobertBaron Okay, a fair test using the Diagnostic Tools in Visual Studio showed that your version indeed was less heavy on the CPU. Thank you all for your input and help.

Comment: @user11903887  From MS Docs "The HashSet<T> class provides high-performance set operations. "  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each rule In RulesObject
    If rule.action = NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW AndAlso TextBox1.Text.Contains(rule.name.ToString) = False Then
        TextBox1.Text += rule.name & vbnewline
    End If
Next
```

The above is one way to do it. It simply checks whether it's already added to the textbox. Btw, I don't know offhand whether or not `rule.name` is already a string so I added `.ToString`; if it's already a string, you don't need to add that.

Also, most of us would recommend using `Option Strict`, and declaring your variables as a type. i.e. `Dim myVar as String = "some string"`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That's surely one good way to do it. I'm curious if there's other ways as well. Also, I'm still curious on why it behaves like it does.

I upvoted you but since I'm new here it doesn't show yet.

Comment: By understanding why it behaves like it does one could find a more solid solution for it I believe. What do you think? I have a theory. Maybe the results are for inbound and oubound rules, hence the double results. I don't know how to prove this theory though.

Comment: Quite possible. There's a quick way to test theory; create an inbound or outbound rule for some app and leave out the opposite rule, and check your code again to see if only 1 item shows up. ;)

Comment: Looking a bit closer at your code, you only test for `NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW`; which means both inbound and outbound rules for an app may be set to Allow, so it could be showing both in and out rules when they're both set to Allow. You should examine the `rule` object closer if you're looking for other values to test against.

Comment: Tested this theory and yes, it was correct. If there's only one inbound OR outbound rule then I receive only one name.

Comment: Also, try adding an inbound rule for an app set to Allow, and an outbound rule for the same app set to Deny, and then test your code. My bet is only 1 will show up as well.